# Can dask read compressed files in blocks?

Tags: python, dask

Is Dask able to read compressed files in chunks?

I receive a couple of errors in [this notebook](https://gist.github.com/rhaksw/9af4f17e71e62634796fc9867d705afc) when reading a .xz file,

```
import dask.bag as db

bag = db.read_text('data/1-input/RC_2018-09.xz', blocksize=100e6).map(json.loads)
```

> ValueError: Cannot infer logical size from file compressed with compression='xz'
>
> ValueError: Cannot do chunked reads on files compressed with compression='xz'. To read, set blocksize=None

Explicitly setting `compression='xz'` also causes an error.

Digging deeper, I see some lines regarding xz files in [compression.py](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/dask/bytes/compression.py) are commented out, so I wonder if this is something that's been disabled.

According to the [xz specs](https://tukaani.org/xz/format.html), it does support random-access reading up to a limited blocksize.

This is not critical for me - I can always decompress and then run Dask - it would just save some disk space.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

XZ does support compression, but it's very rare in practice.  The cost to maintain it ended up being greater than it was used, so maintainers stopped maintaining this feature.  If you're interested in picking up maintenance then that would be welcome and it would be possible to add it back again.